# Specifying a non-NavigationWindow as the main window in App.xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

The following XAML in app.xaml works:

```
<Application.MainWindow>
    <NavigationWindow Visibility="Visible" Source="MainWindow.xaml"></NavigationWindow>
</Application.MainWindow>
```

But changing this to

```
<Application.MainWindow>
    <Window Visibility="Visible" Source="MainWindow.xaml"></Window>
</Application.MainWindow>
```

Means that I can't specify the `Source`.  Can anyone tell me how to specify the source for a non-navigation window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Source` is Dependency Property on navigation window and not available on Window.

In case you want to make `MainWindow.xaml` as *startup window for your application* i.e. MainWindow of application, you can specify `StartupUri` on Application itself:

```
<Application StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
```

---

In case you need *to set Application MainWindow*, you have to provide instance of window like this:

```
<Application xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ActualNamespace">
    <Application.MainWindow>
        <local:MainWindow/>
    </Application.MainWindow>
</Application>
```

Replace `ActualNamespace` with namespace where `MainWindow` resides.

Comment: Damn was just typing startupuri... +1

Comment: Happens sometimes.. Thanks.. :)

Comment: No - I want to using the `MainWindow` property for another purpose.  The MSDN documentation seems to imply that it can be either a `Window` or a `NavigationWindow`

Comment: Whilst that does work, it creates an instance of the form (as you said).  Is it not possible to simply flag the main window without instantiating it?

Comment: No, if you won't set that explicitly. Starup window automatically will be set as MainWindow for your app and that makes perfect sense. Why you wan't to set flag on it?